# How to solve $x\tan^2 x-\tan x+x-1=0$

Tags: trigonometry

One of my homework questions is to find where the gradient of $\frac{x}{1+\tan x}$ is zero. Using the quotient rule got me to $\frac{1+\tan x-x\sec^2 x}{(1+\tan x)^2}$. I know I can ignore the denominator when the equation is equal to $0$, thus resulting in $1+\tan x-x\sec^2 x$, which I rewrote as $x\tan^2 x-\tan x+x-1$ (using $\sec^2 A=\tan^2 A+1$, and multiplying through by $-1$)

So how do I solve this equation now?

Comment: I do not think that you can solve this algebraically. Wolframalpha agrees with that. You can solve it numerically. For example using Newton's Method. Are you sure this is the original function?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=d%2Fdx+x%2F%281%2Btan%28x%29%29++%3D0

Answer (score 0):

If you remember that, up to few weeks ago, $x=\cos(x)$ did not show explicit solution even with special functions, there is no hope to find the zero of function
$$f(x)=x\tan^2 (x)-\tan (x)+x-1$$and numerical methods would be required.

However, you can have quite good approximations.

First, inspection
$$f(0)=-1 \qquad f\left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)=\frac{\pi }{2}-2 <0\qquad f\left(\frac{\pi }{3}\right)=\frac{4 \pi }{3}-1-\sqrt{3} >0$$ the solution is just above $\frac{\pi }{4}$.

Make a series expansion around this value
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2} (\pi -4)+\pi  \left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)+2 (1+\pi )
   \left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{3}\right)^4\right)$$
So, using more and more terms and solving the polynomial in $\left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)$, you will have
$$x_{(1)}=\frac \pi 4+\left(\frac{2}{\pi }-\frac{1}{2}\right)=0.922018$$
$$x_{(2)}=\frac \pi 4+\frac{\sqrt{16+3 (4-\pi ) \pi }-\pi }{4 (1+\pi )}=0.892036$$

while the solution is $x=0.887829$.